# Oracle Query on 24 tables with same columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have 24 tables table1, table2, table3 ... with same columns to keep track of customers data on hourly basis and one rate table which rate is applied for a specific hour, rateId is a foregin key in all the 24 other tables, i need a dynamic query to fetch data from those tables on date and time basis. Can any one provide an example or guide me for that query.

Comment: Do you have the partitioning option?

Answer (score 2):

You should not store the same data in 24 different tables.  Partitioning (mentioned in a comment) is a very good solution when you have lots and lots of data and want to split it for performance reasons.

In any case, one way to structure your query is:

```
select t.*
from ((select * from table1) union all
      (select * from table2) union all
      . . .
      (select * from table24)
     ) t
where <whatever you want>
```

You can then join this to whatever other tables you like (using `rateId`, for instance), filter on the fields, or whatever.

If you need to know the table where something came from, then you can get this as well:

```
select t.*
from ((select t.*, 1 as which from table1 t) union all
      (select t.*, 2 as which from table2 t) union all
      . . .
      (select t.*, 24 as which from table24 t)
     ) t
where <whatever you want>
```

Note:  I am using `*` here because the OP explicitly states that the tables have the same format.  Even so, it is probably a good idea to list all the columns in each subquery.

EDIT:

As Bill suggests in the comment, you might want to turn this into a view.  That way, you can write lots of queries on the tables, without worrying about the detailed tables.  (And, better yet, you can fix the data structure by combining the tables, then change the view, and existing queries will work).

Comment: If the OP were to take this approach, I would go on further to suggest that they turn this SQL into a view call AllData or something like that.

Comment: @BillGregg . . . I totally agree.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Do you know how to tell the optimizer that each table contains only exactly one hour, kind of "partition pruning"? I tried check constraint, but they didn't help.